# Using user input in classes

Tags: python

I have only been programming for about a month and my question is this. Once I am done in the class defining the functions and class, how can I use the user input with the functions. Any help is appreciated the can shed a little light.

```
class employee:


    def __init__(self,first,last,pay,hours):
        self.first = raw_input("whats your first name")
        self.last = raw_input("whats your last name") 
        self.pay = int(input("how much do you make an hour"))
        self.hours = int(input("how many hours do you have"))



        def raise_amount(self, amount):
            self.pay = int(input('how much would you like to raise the employee pay'))



    def overtime(self,overtime):
        if self.hours !=39:
            print ("there is an error you have overtime standby")
            num1 = self.pay / 2
            overtime = num1 + self.pay
            print self.first, + self.overtime(self.hours)



print employee(self.hours)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What does "use the user input with the functions." mean? And you really shouldn't be calling `input` inside the constructor. What happens if you want to create an Employee from existing data?

Comment: Also, highlight your code and press `ctrl+k` while editing to format it properly.

Comment: Do use the [edit] link to fix the formatting of your code. Since python uses whitespace for syntax, it's strongly discouraged for other users to fix these issues (unlike other parts of Stack Overflow), only you can be sure what indentation you're actually using.

Answer (score 5):

As it stands this class does not make a lot of sense, particularly this bit:

```
class employee:

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay,hours):
        self.first = raw_input("whats your first name")
        self.last = raw_input("whats your last name") 
        self.pay = int(input("how much do you make an hour"))
        self.hours = int(input("how many hours do you have"))
```

By giving `__init__` four arguments (in addition to `self`), it means that when you instantiate the class (via `my_employee = employee(...)`), you will have to pass all of those arguments, i.e. in your code you have to write `my_employee = employee("John", "Cleese", "£2", "5 hours")`. But that's pointless, because the `__init__` function then completely ignores all of that information when it sets the attributes of the class, and instead uses user input. You just want to do this:

```
class employee:

    def __init__(self):
        self.first = raw_input("whats your first name")
        self.last = raw_input("whats your last name") 
        self.pay = int(input("how much do you make an hour"))
        self.hours = int(input("how many hours do you have"))

    ...

my_employee = employee()
```

It would be better however to create a general employee class, and then in circumstances where you need to create an employee via input, you can still do so. Specifically:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, hours):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.hours = hours

    ...

your_employee = Employee(input("First name: "), input("Last name: "),
    int(input("Pay: ")), int(input("Hours: ")))
```

Comment: I'll reiterate though, just because I think it really is important: you should not be asking for user input within the constructor. This forces you to manually type the data every time you want to create an Employee. What if you have a file containing the information already? Ask for input outside of the constructor, and pass the data in.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, that is completely true. I didn't want to second guess what this person is trying to do because it is presumably just for educational purposes. But in real code yes, set `self.first = first` and so on, and if you need to instantiate the class with user input, do `employee(input(...), ...)`.

Comment: I know it's offtopic for the question, I just thought that that's a habit that should be shot down before it gains any momentum for the OP. I didn't mean to detract from your answer. +1

Comment: No you are right, I updated my answer to accommodate your comment.